# mod_rewrite: neglect /directory/ in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

for better URL Structure I want to have `mysite.com/downloads/file.pdf` even though the file lies in `mysite.com/assets/downloads/file.pdf`.

How can I link to `mysite.com/downloads/file.pdf` but run `mysite.com/assets/downloads/file.pdf` with mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(downloads/.+)/?$ assets/$1 [L,NC]
```